# How to pass username and password to $resource

Tags: angularjs, rest, authentication, header, resources

I'm new to Angular and I want to set my login form to allow my users to login. I receive this error:

> Cannot read property 'setUserPass' of undefined

I have this service:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('myapp');
    app.service('loginSvc',function($resource){
        var username="";
        var password="";
        self=this;

        self.setUserPass=function(user,pass){
          self.username=user;
          self.password=pass;
        };

        return $resource("http://localhost:8080/user",{},
                {get: {method:'GET',
                headers : { authorization : "Basic "+ 
                btoa(self.username+":"+self.password)}}});
      });

})();
```

and in the controller:

```
        var username="xxxx";
        var password="xxx";
        var self = this;
        loginSvc().setUserPass(self.username,self.password);
        self.auth = loginSvc().get();`enter code here`
```

How should I pass the username and password to my service?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you injected the service into your controller and use the reference that you assigned to it.

Try:

```
    angular.module('myapp')
      .controller('UserCtrl', ['loginSvc', function (loginSvc) {
        var username="xxxx";
        var password="xxx";
        var self = this;
        loginSvc.setUserPass(self.username,self.password);
        self.auth = loginSvc.get();
      }]);
```

Comment: Yes I injected that exactly like this, It works if i hard coding a password and an username in service but does not work with parameters :-(

Comment: Did you try loginSvc.setUserPass(self.username,self.password); rather than   loginSvc().setUserPass(self.username,self.password);?